# Are column widths variable in tkinter Text widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

I'm trying to display a bill in a tkinter `Text` box, but I can't get all the columns (like name, price, etc.) to align. Is it because some letters are wider than others?

```
ct=5.0
for i in lst_bill:
    txt_bill.insert(ct,'\n' + str(int(ct-4)))  # for sl.no
    txt_bill.insert(tk.END,' '*11+i[0])
    txt_bill.insert(tk.END,' '*(40-len(i[0]))+str(i[1]))
    txt_bill.insert(tk.END,' '*(10-len(str(i[1]))) +i[2])
    ct+=1
```

`lst_bill` looks something like this:

```
[['Orange Cake', 20, 'milk'], ['Red Velvet Cake', 30, 'None'], 
 ['BlackCoffee', 5, 'None'], ['Pumpkin Pie', 10, 'Milk']]
```

[Screenshot of current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2O45.jpg)

Comment: The varying character widths look like they're the problem. You can define tab stops in a `Text` widget to overcome this — here's some documentation titled [Setting tabs in a `Text` widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20190428233236id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-tabs.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is because you are using a variable-width font.

You can use tab stops instead of padding the data with spaces. For example, to set the tab stops at 50 pixels, 200 pixels, and then 250 pixels, and with the third column being right-justified you can do it like this:

```
txt_bill.configure(tabs="50 200 right 250")
ct=5.0
for i in lst_bill:
    txt_bill.insert("end", f"{int(ct-4)}\t{i[0]}\t{i[1]}\t{i[2]}\n")
    ct += 1
```

[image: screenshot]

You might want to compute the widths based on the font and the maximum width of the data in each column, but this gives the general idea.

The canonical description of how to define tabstops is in the [tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M-tabs) for the text widget.